# Show multiple divs of hidden content at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 20 divs on a page, 4 of them are displayed initially with a more link at the bottom. Clicking the more link should make the next 4 divs visible until eventually all of the divs are visible.

The only note is that there is never a set amount of divs, there could be 5, 20 or 102 the number is not static or known.

I cannot use AJAX for the solution, so having all of the content on the page and appending 4 divs at a time to the visible list is the workaround.

Does anyone know a plugin that does this or have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:lt`  and `:hidden` selectors and select the first four hidden div elements:

```
$('#your-button').click(function(){
   $('.divs:hidden:lt(4)').show()
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LyTbn/

You can also use `slice` method:

```
$('div:hidden').slice(0, 4).show()
```

Comment: great way to show the hidden divs, but what if he has to show more or less than 4

Comment: @defau1t Well, then only a number should be changed?

Comment: I know that but I am usually not a fan of changing code every time you have to make a change. I dont think this is reusable code

Comment: @defau1t _I am usually not a fan of changing code every time you have to make a change_ Can you elaborate please?